# Re-execute Python interpreter with a different script effectively

Tags: python

I'm working on a wrapper script written in Python. The wrapper is supposed to choose another Python script based on the system state and execute it (using the absolute path). There is no need to return to the parent script.

It should be noted that I have no control over the scripts being run. They can use `__name__` checks, access `sys.argv` and it should all behave like if the script was run directly.

Right now, I'm using `os.execl()`:

```
import os, sys

# ...

os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, new_script, *sys.argv[1:])
```

But I can count at least three issues with that:

1. Any options passed to the Python interpreter are not preserved (e.g. `python -v wrapper` stops being verbose on re-exec);
2. The Python interpreter is re-executed unnecessarily (with PyPy it adds 0,7s on my system);
3. It relies on `sys.executable` being useful, and the docs say that:

> If Python is unable to retrieve the real path to its executable, `sys.executable` will be an empty string or `None`.
>   
>   I'm wondering what replacement I should use for the `os.execl` call to solve all the issues. So far, I can tell that:

1. `execfile()` would probably work but it was removed in Python3 and re-implementing it by hand AFAICS is ugly (because of the encoding issues). I'm not sure what other implications can `execfile()` have;
2. `imp.load_module()` would probably work but it's a bit hacky and was deprecated in Python3.3. It probably can suffer Python3 encoding issues as well.

Which solution do you suggest I use?

---

Edit: I'd forget. The solution has to work with Python 2.5+, PyPy and Jython 2.5+.

Comment: Could you `import` the new script?

Comment: That looks fine, but you can just do some validation first,before exec, and also inspect sys.flags to reconstruct the flags.

Comment: I run into cases where the path in `sys.executable` contained spaces and needed to be quoted to work properly.

Comment: You can use `sys.flags` to determine what options were passed to the Python interpreter.

Comment: @martineau: I have the absolute path only. The file doesn't have `.py` suffix or follow any specific rules. It is just a random Python script living in the system.

Comment: @Keith: good one with `sys.flags` but it's a bit cumbersome and probably not really portable to reconstruct the options like that. Not to mention the two remaining points are still valid.

Comment: Well, it's an odd requirement. I don't see why you can't just dynamically import some state specific module.

Comment: To bad about `execfile` because it doesn't care about a file's extension or location -- might be worth the trouble of dealing with the encoding issues.

Comment: @martineau: could you tell me whether and why do you believe that `execfile()` is superior over `imp.load_module()` in this case? You may be right; I've just looked at `tokenize` and it seems simpler to re-implement than I found earlier.

Comment: @MichałGórny: Because the `load_module()` function does more than import the module which don't sound like things you need or want, not to mention that it sounds like really don't even want to import it at all.

Comment: @martineau: You are probably correct. Would you turn that into a short answer so I could give you kudos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use `execfile()` instead of `imp.load_module()`. Although control will be returned to the executive script, one big advantage is that, quoting the docs:

> It is different from the import statement in that it does not use the
>   module administration — it reads the file unconditionally and does not
>   create a new module.

This means the script file can be anywhere, can have any (or no) file extension, and resources aren't wasted doing module-import related tasks.

Doing so automatically accomplishes or avoids the things you desire:

1. interpreter options will be preserved
2. interpreter will not be re-executed unnecessarily
3. it does not rely on the value of `sys.executable`

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
### wrapped script ###

import sys

print("__name__: {0}\nsys.argv: {1}".format(__name__, sys.argv))
```

```
### wrapper script ###

import builtins, sys

my_script = "wrapped_script.py"

print("Executing the wrapped script...")

sys.argv[0] = my_script
with open(my_script, 'r') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        exec(line)
```

Result:

```
$ python3 wrapped_script.py --foo --bar=quux
__name__: __main__
sys.argv: ['wrapped_script.py', '--foo', '--bar=quux']

$ python3 wrapper.py --foo --bar=quux
Executing the wrapped script...
__name__: __main__
sys.argv: ['wrapped_script.py', '--foo', '--bar=quux']
```

Comment: It fails when wrapped script uses backslash continuations…